# Mysql LIMIT operator - equal efficency when not using it?

Tags: mysql, myisam

How is it that when i use LIMIT, mysql checks the same number of rows? and how do i solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explain output is misleading.  Mysql will evaluate the query using the where clause and such, but it'll stop after it find LIMIT number of matching rows (1 in this case).  This is a known issue with mysql:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50168

To clarify... the limit clause will work as expected... it's only the explain output that's inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

The Where clause is processed first. Once the matches are found, the limit is applied on the result set, so all of the rows have to be evaluated to determine if they match the conditions before the limit can be applied.

Comment: but i can't change the flag position so what do i do?